# Problem using Groupby in Python for date time. How to make a bar plot with Month/Year?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have the following data set:

df

```
OrderDate Total_Charged

7/9/2017 5
7/9/2017 5
7/20/2017 10
8/20/2017 6
9/20/2019 1
```

...

I want to make a bar plot with month_year (X-axis) and Total charged per month/year i.e. sum it over month and year. Firstly, I want to groupby month and year and next make the plot.However, I get error on the first step:

```
df["OrderDate"]=pd.to_datetime(df['OrderDate'])
monthly_orders=df.groupby([(df.index.year),(df.index.month)]).sum()["Total_Charged"]
```

Got following error:

> AttributeError: 'RangeIndex' object has no attribute 'year'

What am I doing wrong (what does the error mean)? How can i fix it?

Comment: Did you try `df.set_index('OrderDate', inplace=True)` before `monthly_order=...`?

Comment: This is not a entire data set, just a tiny example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you're grouping by the index there. If you want the group by `year` and `month` respectively you could do the following:

```
df["OrderDate"]=pd.to_datetime(df['OrderDate'])
df.groupby([df.OrderDate.dt.year, df.OrderDate.dt.month]).sum().plot.bar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## [`pandas.DataFrame.resample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

- This is a versatile option, that easily implements aggregation over various time ranges (e.g. weekly, daily, quarterly, etc)

### Code:

#### A more expansive dataset:

- This code block sets up the sample dataset.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# list of dates
first_date = datetime(2017, 1, 1)
last_date = datetime(2019, 9, 20)
x = 4
list_of_dates = [date for date in np.arange(first_date, last_date, timedelta(days=x)).astype(datetime)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'OrderDate': list_of_dates,
                   'Total_Charged': [np.random.randint(10) for _ in range(len(list_of_dates))]})
```

[image]

#### Using `resample` for `Monthly Sum`:

- requires a `datetime` index

```py
df.OrderDate = pd.to_datetime(df.OrderDate)
df.set_index('OrderDate', inplace=True)
monthly_sums = df.resample('M').sum()

monthly_sums.plot.bar(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.show()
```

[image]

#### An example with `Quarterly Avg`:

- this shows the versatility of `resample` compared to `groupby`
- `Quarterly` would not be easily implemented with  `groupby`

```py
quarterly_avg = df.resample('Q').mean()

quarterly_avg.plot.bar(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.show()
```

[image]